# $n$-tuples as nested ordered pairs: a formal definition using recursion on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: set-theory, recursion, foundations, natural-numbers

Using conventional set theory as a foundation, there are two most popular definitions of an $n$-tuple of elements of $X$:

- A function $n\to X$.
- For any $x_1,...,x_n \in X$, $(x_1,...,x_n, x_{n+1}) = ((x_1,...,x_n),x_{n+1}).$

I'm interested in how we can formalize the second one. Most say that it is a definition *by induction*. However, the formal way to deal with such matters is *recursion*.

> **Recursion theorem.** Given a set $A$, an element $a$ of $A$ and a function $g\colon A\to A$, there is a unique function $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to A$ such that
>
> - $f(0) = a$,
> - $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f(n+1) = g(f(n))$.

I'm trying to understand how can we use recursion to formalize the second definition of an $n$-tuple.

I can see that we would like a function $f$ with $\mathrm{dom}(f) = \mathbb{N}$ so that

> - $f(0) = \{\varnothing\}$,
> - $f(1) = X$,
> - $f(2) = X \times X$ and
> - $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$, $f(n+1) = f(n) \times X$.

However, I don't see what the codomain of such function can be. It probably can be done with transfinite recursion, but do we really need to use it for something so basic such as this?

Comment: A route that avoids all this: define an $n$-tuple as a function $\{1,\dots,n\}\to X$. Then $\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$ is a notation for the function that is prescribed by $i\mapsto x_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: I know that I am bringing you problems not solutions but there is an issue with the recursive definition. Let us say that we are trying to define an ordered triple ($3$-tuple :)) Then you scheme would suggest we define $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ as $((x_{1},x_{2}),x_{3})$ now we should have defined this already as it is an ordered pair but we haven't because one of its elements ($x_{1},x_{2}$) is not in $X$.

Comment: I know this method. I'm specifically interested in how to formally defined an $n$-tuple $(x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1})$ as an ordered pair $((x_1,...,x_n),x_{n+1})$. The fact that a function $n\to X$ starts with $0$ rather than $1$ has nothing to do with it. Sorry.

Comment: Is there a requirement that the function is surjective? Because otherwise, you could just use the set defined by $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ where $A_0=X$ and $A_{n+1}=\mathcal P(A_n)$ where $\mathcal P$ denotes the power set.

Comment: The second one is not a very good definition of $n$-tuples, because it does not distinguish between a three-element sequence $(a,b,c)$ and a two-element sequence $((a,b),c)$. Essentially, it prevents a pair such as $(a,b)$ from ever being the first element of an ordered pair.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the set $A=\{X^n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ as codomain, where $X^n$ denotes the set of functions $\{1,\dots,n\}\to X$ and $g:A\to A$ is prescribed by $X^n\mapsto X^{n+1}$ and $f(0)=X^0$.