# Exercise 6.4.2 Introduction to Set Theory by Hrbacek and Jech

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion

This is exercise 6.4.2 from the book *Introduction to Set Theory* 3rd ed. by Hrbacek and Jech.

> Using the Recursion Theorem 4.9 show that there is a binary operation $F$ such that
>
> $(a)$ $F(x,1)=0$ for all $x$.
>
> $(b)$ $F(x,n+1)=0$ if and only if there exist $y$ and $z$ such that $x=(y,z)$ and $F(y,n)=0$.
>
> We say that $x$ is an $n$-tuple (where $n\in\omega$, $n>0$) if $F(x,n)=0$. Prove that this definition of $n$-tuples coincides with the one given in Exercise 5.17 in Chapter 3.

For completeness here is Recursion Theorem 4.9 in the book.

> Let $G$ be an operation. There exists an operation $F$ such that $F(z,\alpha)=G(z,F_z\restriction \alpha)$ for all ordinals $\alpha$ and all sets $z$.

What puzzles me about this exercise is the fact that the value of $F(x,n+1)$ depends on the value of $F(y,n)$ for all sets $y$, not only $x$.

Any hint on how to proceed? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: For me it's not clear what the domains and codomains of all the operations are. But regarding your concrete problem: if there exist $y$ and $z$ with $x=(y,z)$, then $y$ and $z$ are uniquely defined by that. To make sense of (a) and (b), it helps a lot to reformulate them in terms of the definition of $n$-tuple below (b).

Comment: @Stefan How would you define $F$? I tried to provide a solution below.

Comment: I find both your question and your answer hard to understand, at least without being familiar with the book.

Comment: @Stefan The question basically asks to formally define $n$-tuples recursively: $(x_1,...,x_n, x_{n+1}) = ((x_1,...,x_n),x_{n+1})$. How would you do it ?

Comment: Yes, I know, but how to do it formally depends a lot on how the theory is developped in the book.

Comment: @Stefan The chapter in the book covers the transfinite recursion theorem for ordinals:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction#Transfinite_recursion .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what the authors had in mind, but I think we can proceed as follows (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2890709/522332)).

**Lemma.** For any set $A$ there exists a unique sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ satisfying

1. $f_1=A$.
2. $f_{n+1}=f_n\times A$ for all $n\in \omega$ with $n\geq 1$.

Let us call such sequence the *cartesian product sequence of $A$*, and denote $f_n$ by $A^n$ (not to be confused with the set of all functions from $n$ to $A$).

**Proof.** Apply the Recursion Theorem 4.9 with the operation

$$G(x,y)=\begin{cases} x \text{ if } y \text{ is a function with domain } 1 \\ y(\alpha)\times x \text{ if } y \text{ is a function with domain } \alpha+1 \text{ for some ordinal } \alpha\geq1 \\ \emptyset \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

and then apply the Axiom of Replacement (see also the proof of Theorem 3.6 in the book). Uniqueness can be shown by induction.

---

Now we say that $x$ is an $n$-tuple ($n\in \omega$, $n>0$) if $x\in A^n$ for some set $A$, i.e. we define

$$F(x,n)=\begin{cases}0 \text{ if } (n,x)\in f , \text{ where } f \text{ is the cartesian product sequence of some set } A\\ 1 \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then one can show that $(a)$ and $(b)$ hold (note that $A\subset B$ implies $A^n\subset B^n$).

Comment: I don't understand why you don't define $G$ in a way that the $F$ that exists by the Recursion Theorem is precisely the $F$ you need. In other words, I would expect $G$ to have the values $0$ and $1$. As it is, I don't see any connection between $G$ and the rest of your proof.

Comment: @Stefan Probably this is what the authors intended, but I couldn't find a suitable definition of $G$ that does the job.  Any suggestions? Right now am defining $n$-tuples as elements of $A^n$ for some set $A$, where $A^n$ is defined recursively by $A^{n+1}=A^n \times A$.